# Laravel Testing Authentication failed asserting

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel

I have already enabled filter in my setUp function. My test function is like this:

```
public function testShowImport() {
    $this->be(User::first());

    $this->call('GET', 'import');
    $this->assertRedirectedToAction('MemberController@getImportIndex');
    //$this->assertRedirectedTo('import'); ---> the same error message
}
```

However when I run the test, I got this error message:

```
Failed asserting that Illuminate\Http\Response Object (...) is an instance of class "Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse"
```

I searched many posts and they say I must enable filter. But I have already enabled it from the start.

I have been stuck at this for hours.

Thank you for reading

Comment: So you're calling `Route::enableFilters()` in the setup method?

Comment: Yes, I called it in setUp method

Comment: Have you tried calling it again in your test. I think Laravels `TestCase` class calls the method `setup` with no camel casing.